# How to encrypt pdf's using the same password as is used to login to Flask site?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, xhtml2pdf

I have a basic Flask site set up at pythonanywhere.com. I've been following along the Flask mega tutorial and I have set up a database of users that stores the login name and password hash. The actual password isn't stored. I want my web app to have the ability to create and encrypt pdf's. I want to know if there's a way to encrypt the pdf's using the same password as what's used to log in to the site.

Here's my pdfexport.py file:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa             # import python module
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import string
import random

# Utility function
def convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename):
    # open output file for writing (truncated binary)
    resultFile = open(outputFilename, "w+b")

    # convert HTML to PDF
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(
            sourceHtml,                # the HTML to convert
            dest=resultFile)           # file handle to recieve result

    # close output file
    resultFile.close()                 # close output file

    # return True on success and False on errors
    return pisaStatus.err

def add_encryption(input_pdf, output_pdf, password):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(input_pdf)

    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    pdf_writer.encrypt(user_pwd=password, owner_pwd=None,
                   use_128bit=True)

    with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as fh:
        pdf_writer.write(fh)

def random_char(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(y))
```

Here's my models.py

```
from flask_app import db, login, app
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from time import time
import jwt
#from app import app

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "usr"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    [...]
```

I suspect what I want to do isn't possible because the actual password isn't stored, but wanted to check anyways.

Comment: while the password istn stored you will receive it in the login request and then hash it to compare it to the hash you have stored. So there will be a point in your app where you will have the password in clear text. However for you to encypt the pdf with that password would requireyou to hold the password in memory during the users session for you to utilise it later to encypt the pdf. Its never a good idea to hold clear text passwords in memory or stored for later.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle. A wild thought, store a blank PDF template in a blob field per user whenever a user's password is changed (because at this point the plain text password is known). Set the user_pwd to the user's password and set the owner_pwd to a known system password. When you create a PDF for the user, use the blank template as a starting point. You will need to decrypt with the known owner password before doing any operations.